# Question about Compactly Supported functions

Tags: functions, compactness

Suppose I have a compactly supported function $f$ defined with $supp f \subset I=  ]0,1[$.
Let $K=supp f$.

Is this statement true:

We can assume without loss of generality that there exists $ \alpha, \beta \in I$ such that $ K \subseteq [\alpha ,  \beta ]$ and $ f(\alpha)=f(\beta)=0$.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to start?

Answer (score 2):

My idea how to start is so good that a start becomes a finish. :-) Put $$\alpha=\frac {\inf\operatorname{supp} f}2,\beta=1-\frac{1-\sup\operatorname{supp} f}2.$$